# Integral word problem. Did I set this up correctly?

Tags: definite-integrals

Here is the question:

> Use the method of cylindrical shells to find the volume generated by rotating the region bounded by the given curves about the specified x-axis.

Here are the parameters:

$$y = 4x - x^2, y = 3\text {; about }x = 1$$

So here are my choices for radius and height:

radius = $x - 1$

height = $4x - x^2 - 3$

So...is this setup right?

$$ \int_1^3 2 \pi (x - 1) ( 4x - x^2 - 3)\, dx$$

Comment: looks good to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.

The volume of revolution is presented by $$\int_1^3 2 \pi (x - 1) ( 4x - x^2 - 3)\, dx$$

and you have explained it well in detail.

Comment: Ok cool... my main concern was my calculation of radius and height.